# VMWare Server on Vista x64

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, vmware

Does it work at all?
I tried to install VMWare server 2.0 on Vista x64.
Could not open the VM Console. It requires a IE addon. 
Tried to install it, Installer succeeds, but VMConsole keeps complaining about the same issue, that it needs an IE addon.

I switched back to VMware server 1.x. Couldn't install it either, because the drivers are not signed.

Solutions? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem initially on Windows 7 x64. Here is how I got it to work.

1. Save the .exe provided by the remote console install link
2. Close IE and run the .exe to install the remote console add-on
3. Open IE (make sure it's not 64-bit if you have IE 8)
4. From the Tools menu select "Manage Add-Ons"
5. Select "Downloaded Controls" from the "Show" drop-down in the lower left corner of the screen
6. Select the remote console add-on and make sure it is enabled
7. Login to the VMWare server and open a console
8. In the Yellow toolbar that appears at the top of IE allow the add-on to run.

That's what worked for me.  Hope that helps you as well.

Comment: Thanks. tried the steps. However, add-in does not show up in IE addons. Tried installing it a few times with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely remember that you need to install the add-on while using Internet Explorer in administrator mode or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I can sympathize with your issue as I had similar problems while installing it on XP x64. The way I resolved it on XP x64 is uninstall all the non-essential components and re-installed VMWare Server, then re-installed the components.

As far as on the Vista kernel, i've been running VMWare Server 2.0 fine on Server 08 x86 for months now.

Have you checked out the [VMWare community forums](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/server/server2)? They're occasionally useful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're running the 32-bit version of Internet Explorer and not the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer.

The 32-bit version is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`; the 64-bit version is located at `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`.